# Does GPU RAM make a difference in an Eevee Render?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I was wondering if the amount of RAM your GPU has makes a difference in Eevee rendering. In Cycles the reason large scenes couldn't be rendered on GPU and had to be rendered on CPU was because the GPU RAM was usually smaller than the system RAM. (i.e. my system RAM is 32gb and my GPU RAM is 4gb). I am shopping for a new GPU and I was wondering if low GPU RAM causes limitations in Eevee like it did in Cycles. I know from looking at Window's Task Manager that both the CPU and GPU workloads increase during render. I don't know enough about Eevee and what of it is done on CPU and what of it is done on GPU to know if the GPU RAM makes a difference. Does GPU RAM limit scene complexity while rendering with Eevee?